# bother and intrude question

Tags: will-be-going

```
    There is no need to ___ with insurance.
    I am not going to ___ to comment on what you told me.
    I am sorry to ___ you at this time of night.
    I will tell Joe not to ___ about being there then.
```

Please, I want to choose one of the following to complete each sentence.

```
a) bother
b) intrude
c) interfere
d) trespass
```

Comment: Do you only wish to fill those blanks or you need an answer with appropriate explanation?

Comment: only answer without any comments.

Comment: Ok, sorry but have one more confusion so writing this comment: do you wish to include all four or any two or any three?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an assignment and does not seek to understand the words, language or the reason for the choice.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1) There's no need to **bother** with insurance.

2) I am not going to **bother** to comment on what you told me.

3) I am sorry to **bother** you at this time of night.

4) I will tell Joe not to **bother** about being there then.

NB : Blanks are filled with bold words.

Comment: These are all incorrect except 2)

Comment: Please post the correct answer or edit my answer..

Comment: @framawi : my pleasure..

Comment: This question is off topic. It may be appropriate for English Language Learners site. As to the correct answer, all the sentences would take **bother** in the form they are written.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this thing. But, all are the synonyms of bother and OP wants to use all of them. So, I have answered whatever suits the sentence construction.

Comment: But they do not fit the sentence structures! For example 3) would need *intrude **on*** to be correct. *Trespass about being there* makes no sense in English. *Interfere* has nothing to do with *insurance*.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think it will be like this:  -1 down vote unaccept
 

1) There's no need to interfere with insurance.

2) I am not going to bother to comment on what you told me.

3) I am sorry to bother you at this time of night.

4) I will tell Joe not to bother about being there then.

Comment: This is a typical Cambridge English exam question where the candidate has to decide which word fits ALL the example sentences. There can be only one correct answer.

Comment: @framawi It's "There's no need to [**bother**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bother_1?q=bother) with insurance" Look up the word, [**bother**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/british/bother) in order to learn and improve your English. Asking a non-expert the answer to an old English exam question, will not help you to memorise the meaning of the word, nor understand *why* it is the correct choice.

Comment: @bib: In its current form, this question **isn't** suitable for ELL because it does not contain enough research.

Comment: @framawi - Sweet72 has given you the right answer; you ought to accept it. The answer at the car rental counter when the agent tries to sell you insurance is, "No thanks, I'm not going to _bother_ with insurance" – not *interfere*. As to Matt's comment, this question could be improved to be a good fit for [ell.se], but I'd expect you'd at least start by consulting a dictionary and explain **why** you're still confused, as opposed to just asking for the answer straight up. The place to ask for answers without any research or explanation is Yahoo! Answers, not the Stack Exchange.